# primeng icons appearing as boxes within primeng control

Tags: angular, primeng, angular8, primeicons

I have created sample angular application in stackblitz and imported all packages to get primeng working.

my `"styles"`look like this in angular.json

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",              
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079742/fontawesome-icons-appearing-as-boxes-within-primeng-controls) but could not find any thing similar.

Here is [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hemant-primengicon-issue) link.

**UPDATE 1**

I realized there are few warning on console complain about '`Failed to decode downloaded fon`t:'

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: <URL>
(index):1 Failed to decode downloaded font: https://hemant-primengicon-issue.stackblitz.io/fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.woff2
(index):1 Failed to decode downloaded font: https://hemant-primengicon-issue.stackblitz.io/fonts/primeicons.ttf
(index):1 Failed to decode downloaded font: https://hemant-primengicon-issue.stackblitz.io/fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.woff
(index):1 Failed to decode downloaded font: https://hemant-primengicon-issue.stackblitz.io/fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-regular.ttf
(index):1 Failed to decode downloaded font: https://hemant-primengicon-issue.stackblitz.io/fonts/primeicons.woff
```

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, but it seems you're not alone: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=56030

Comment: true.  there is one issue : https://github.com/primefaces/primeicons/issues/104  but development team keeps on saying they can not reproduce it.

Comment: Post your stack blitz link in that issue. Maybe that will help them figure it out.

Comment: Hello, I have a similar problem. What Prime's version are you using? @user2243747